# Ajax Post and weird http response in Chrome. I can't reproduce the issue locally

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, kendo-ui

I am using a KendoUI AutoComplete component that is pulling back data as soon as the users starts entering digits. We have one School district that is having problems.

In Chrome, they are seeing the wait "spinney" with an apparent disconnect in the response from the server, possible unhandled exception. The status is ERR_EMPTY_REPONSE. It seems like the when the user stops typing the current request may be aborted somehow. But I have a onSuccess function that is firing. From that ajax call. Here is the code portion:

```
//TEMP METHODS TO REDUCE CLUTTER. These should be moved out and encapsulated
renderEntitySearch: function (
    targetElement,//Parent Div
    searchUrl,//The url to perform the search and get results
    detailsUrl,//The url to get details view when a search item is selected
    rootUrl,//For images
    searchText,//Grey text in empty search box
    homeUrl//This is used to push the back view onto the view controller when a selection is made
    )
{

    var that=this;
    var textBox = $("#" + targetElement);
    textBox.focus(function () { this.value = ""; });

    textBox.width(325);
    textBox.addClass('il-searchBox');
    textBox.kendoAutoComplete({
        dataTextField: "EntityName",
        placeholder: searchText,
        //template: "<mark>${data.EntityTypeName}</mark> ${data.EntityName}",
        template: "<img src='" + rootUrl + "Images/Icons/16/${data.EntityTypeName}.png'/> <mark>${data.EntityName}</mark>",
        width: "225px",
        highlightFirst: true,
        dataSource: {
            dataType: "json",
            type: "GET",

            transport: {
                read: {
                    type: "json",
                    url: searchUrl,
                    data: function () {
                        return { searchTerm: $("#" + targetElement).val() };
                    }
                }
            },
            serverFiltering: true
        },
        select: function(e)
        {
            var dataItem = this.dataItem(e.item.index());
            if (dataItem.EntityID.length > 0) {
                that.loadView(
                    {
                        viewName: "mainView",                            
                        alwaysRefresh: true,
                        resetHistory: true,
                        homeViewOptions: 
                        {
                            viewName: "mainView",                                   
                            alwaysRefresh: true,
                            resetHistory: true,
                            url: homeUrl                                                            
                        },
                        url: detailsUrl,
                        data: { EntityType: dataItem.EntityType, EntityID: dataItem.EntityID }
                    });
            }
        }
            //searchCallBack
    });
},
```

And the server code to conduct the search.

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0)]
public JsonResult Search(string searchTerm)
{
    //This method returns data to the ajax initiated search request. This is the function that fires when the user types in text in the search bar to return 
    //search results.

    if ((searchTerm) == null) return null;
    //Call the search services and return the data as json

    SearchRequest _request = new SearchRequest();
    _request.User = MyWebApp.Session.CurrentUser;
    _request.SearchFlags = UserTypeEnum.All;
    _request.SearchTerm = searchTerm.ToLower();

    return Json(new My.Controllers.Data.SearchController().PerformQuickSearch(_request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

The teacher has been helpful in working with us. We received an F12 screenshot of the error that we are not able to reproduce.

Chrome Response when the error occurs.

[image]

Normal, what I see. (chrome)

1. Get the (Pending) text for the GET

[image]

2. Wait for entire Response to be read then change the status to OK. This is the part that her browser does not like.

[image]

My working output in IE, Fiddler returns a similar result for the search.[image]

I think that she may be locked into an old version of Chrome that had an issue handling the situation where a header is read but the full response does not include data, And/or there is a firewall or other add-on running that sees this as abnormal.

Anyone experience this or have insight on how I can fix this?

**UPDATE** : Thanks for the comments

I just got an update from the field. The ticket I sent to Telerik seemed to pay off. The properties on the data source were not correct. The data source should be defined as follows:

```
dataSource: {
     transport: {
          read: {
              dataType: "json",
              type: "GET",
              url: searchUrl,
              data: function () {
                  return { searchTerm: $("#" + targetElement).val() };
              }
          }
      },
```

However, this does not explain how this went through our QA and one client was having a problem even when the configuration was off.

Comment: are you saying this happens each time? did she try with a different browser? are they running their own server?

Comment: also, your DS definition is weird; there is no type and dataType option for the DS, these belong to the AJAX request (read action); also, the type option for read should be GET

Comment: seems like firewall issue, did you ever tried on other machine in the same firewall(network)?

Comment: Does the client make a cross-domain ajax request? That could be the reason the browser complains

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normally caused when you have an external program (such as a virus) attempting to intercept the data. For security purposes chrome cancels the request. I would recommend doing a full virus scan and checking your programs and features for any new programs that may have been added recently. Sometimes chrome extensions may do this as well. Perhaps one that recently updated or a new one you added is causing the problem.

Comment: I fixed their issue by clearing up some things in the transport. I will give you the bounty since you answered and the explanation above seems plausible to the different responses we are seeing on different networks.